# remove output when nohup is called from a function bashrc

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to write a function for my .bashrc that calls a nohup.
It does work but ignores the redirection of the output and makes a nohup.out file in the same folder.

it works fine when I type it in the shell.

```
   function show {
       nohup /bin/bash -c "xdg-open $1" > /dev/null 2>&1
   }
```

I was expecting that once the output is redirected it will not generate the out file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirections go after the compound commands.

```
function show {
   nohup /bin/bash -c "xdg-open $1" 
} > /dev/null 2>&1
```

And see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions for more.